# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory' available

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I want to disable KAFKA consumer being autostarted and tried the below code

```
@Component
class Customizer {

    Customizer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory,
            @Value("${start.containers:true}") boolean start) {

        factory.setAutoStartup(start);
    }

}
```

it works fine when I disable the Test cases however I see the below error while test cases are getting executed.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'kafkaConsumerCustomizer' defined in
> file [kafkaConsumerCustomizer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed
> through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate.

I have added the empty default constructor to make the test cases pass however it is always referring the empty default constructor but not the parameterized constructor. Is there a way to use the empty default constructor only for the test cases and parameterized constructor otherwise?

I have tried below solutions

**Solution#1:**

```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
     
    
    @Component
    class KafkaConsumerCustomizer {
      KafkaConsumerCustomizer() {
      }
    
     
    
      KafkaConsumerCustomizer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory,
             @Value("${consumer.autostart:true}") boolean start) {
        factory.setAutoStartup(start);
      }
    }
```

**For Solution#1:**
the default constructor got executed and could not start/stop the consumers

**Solution#2:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

 

@Component
class KafkaConsumerCustomizer {
  @Autowired
  AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory;
  
  @Value("${consumer.autostart:true}")
  private boolean start;

 

  KafkaConsumerCustomizer() {
    factory.setAutoStartup(start);
    System.out.println("Setting Autostart: " + start);
  }
}
```

**For Solution#2:**
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}u2028   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767)

How to disable KAFKA consumer being autostarted without breaking the test cases ?

**Update:**
Have removed the @Component tag from KafkaConsumerCustomizer class

```
class KafkaConsumerCustomizer {
  KafkaConsumerCustomizer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory,
         @Value("${consumer.autostart:true}") boolean start) {
    factory.setAutoStartup(start);
  }
}
```

as well as I have updated the main Configuration class

```
@Getter
@RefreshScope
@Import(processorConfig.class)
@Configuration
public class appSpringConfiguration {
  @Bean
  KafkaConsumerCustomizer kafkaCustomizer() {
    return new KafkaConsumerCustomizer();
  }
}
```

It is still throwing the below error:

> SpringConfiguration.java:[49,12] constructor KafkaConsumerCustomizer
> in class com.xx.KafkaConsumerCustomizer cannot be applied to given
> types; [ERROR]   required:
> org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory,boolean
> [ERROR]   found: no arguments [ERROR]   reason: actual and formal
> argument lists differ in length [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Your second solution would fail with `NullPointerException`. The fields are injected after object construction, you are already accessing them in your constructor. So your second "solution" will break. Also why not just register a bean of type `ContainerCustomizer` to modify the property?

Comment: Why not simply use `KafkaConsumerCustomizer(@Autowired(required = false) AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory, ...)` (and handle the possibility of `factory` being `null`)?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, your tests are not marked `@SpringBootTest`.

You can either add a `mock(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory)` bean to your test configuration, or don't use `@Component` on the customizer; instead add a `@Bean` for it in the main configuration.

Then, it won't be found by component scanning in your tests.

In some other `@Configuration` class, add

```java
@Bean
KafkaConsumerCustomizer cust() {
    return new KafkaConsumerCustomizer();
}
```

or...

```java
@Bean
KafkaConsumerCustomizer cust(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory,
            @Value("${start.containers:true}") boolean start) {
    return new KafkaConsumerCustomizer(factory, start);
}
```

Comment: should I just replace "@Component" tag with "@Bean" in the Customizer class?

Comment: No; it needs to go into a `@Configuration` class - see the edit.

Comment: does it mean we will have 2 files? one as mentioned in the question decorated with "@Component" and another one "@Bean"? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: No, only one; remove the `@Component` and declare it as a `@Bean` instead in a `@Configuration` class that is not used in your tests; that way it won't be picked up when there is no factory bean.

Comment: Gary Russell- as per the suggestion, have updated the code and still facing an issue. Have updated the question with the latest code. It works if I add the default constructor however we want the parameterized constructor to be called to disable/enable the kafka consumer autostart. please suggest.

Comment: The auto wiring will still work. If you want to do it via a constructor, add it as a parameter to the `cust()` bean definition above.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code sample? somehow I don't get it.

Comment: with the above code, it is still connecting with the KAFKA cluster irrespective of setting the autostart as false.

Comment: You are obviously missing something; if you can't figure it out, post a small, stripped down, complete project someplace so I can see what you are doing wrong. I don't see how you can connect if you don't have a container factory bean.

Comment: Can you please help me with - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67211600/kafka-reactor-how-to-disable-kafka-consumer-being-autostarted ?